# Digg.com, Facebook and other's not picking up images properly for site, how to correct?

Tags: html, facebook, web

I'd like to control which images Digg.com, Facebook and others, however I'm meeting with little success.

It was my impression that it should be as simple as adding the following to the head:

```
<link href='/path/to/image.jpg' rel='image_src'>
```

However, nothing seems to pull up that image Digg:
[image: Digg - no image]

And Facebook likewise will not pull up the image(s) I hope for it to display, particularly by default:
[image: Facebook - no image]

**What's the right approach here to solve this primarily for Digg and Facebook** (that is if there are two separate approaches)**?**

Comment: Claudiu's answer is a good one. I would also point out this tool, which helps you troubleshoot these sorts of things: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is good, however none of them mention the aspect of other services getting a defined image.  It appears that indeed you need to use the FB meta properties, of which I was not aware, however that leaves the question of what of defining images for other services such as Digg?

Comment: You should try the same `og:image` on digg as they may have implemented the same OGP

Comment: Good idea @LawrenceCherone, however it unfortunately does not work for Digg it appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:description"
      content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
               a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
               threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
               weapons."/>
```

It's all in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

**Edit:**

Make sure you use the debugger to retest the URL as Facebook caches these types of results for quite a while: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Thanks for the details.  It seems as though simply having the "og:image" property should do the trick, however FB is still not picking up the image.  Are you aware of whether some kind of FB cache needs to expire first or if the other fields must likewise be present for the `ob:image` field to work?

Comment: Edited original answer with the reply :)

Comment: Turns out that by utilizing your answer + correcting the initial post that I issued (I found the problem using the debugger as noted) with the full image path, it now works across the board.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's image tag is:

`<meta property="og:image" content="path">`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your looking for the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) specificity the use of the `property="og:image"` meta tag.

**Example:**

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/FB.png" />`